# Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.2 Code Lens issue on Light theme

Tags: visual-studio-2017, codelens

After an update to version 15.7.2, code lens displays partly unreadable text but only on light theme.

[image: Light theme]

[image: Dark Theme]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 :**
Under Tools->Options-> Environment-> Fonts and Colors with Codelens selected under show settings for, change from any of the Code39Azalea fonts.

**Option 2 :**
Under Tools->Options-> Environment-> Fonts and Colors with Codelens selected under show settings for, Click use defaults, it should reset to calibri font.